# can I treat multi-class classification problem as multi-label classification problem?

Tags: python

If I have a multi-class classification problem,
for example, I want to classify 3 kinds of flowers,
and I need to create the ground truth labels myself.

If the input is

```
[flowerA, flowerB, flowerC]
```

,
after passing resnet the output shape is [3,3].

Typically the ground truth will be like

```
[1,2,3]
```

can I use

```
[ [1,0,0],
  [0,1,0],
  [0,0,1] ]
```

as ground truth instead? the shape of label is [3,3].

I use nn.CrossEntropyLoss as loss function.

Comment: Yes, you pretty much have to do this (tensorflow accepts logits, so you don't have to do it yourself).

Comment: why have you written multi-label? each flower can be either 1/[1,0,0] or 2/[0,1,0] or 3/[0,0,1]. they should not have multiple labels.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention I use pytorch.

Comment: @Ritwick yes, each flower has only one label, but I am not sure if I can use the form of `[1,0,0]` instead of `1`

Comment: yes that is standard practice. that is what you should be using. it is a one hot encoding

Comment: @ Ritwick thank you for your answer! And I wonder if I will get the same results using the form of `[1,0,0]` as `1`?